# phpspreadsheet German date format

Tags: datetime, phpspreadsheet

How can i set the german date format with phpspreadsheet?
If i set the cell to `->setFormatCode(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DDMMYYYY)` it will be displayed in Excel to [Screenshot Excel date format 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPY0y.png)

If i use `->setFormatCode(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\StyleNumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDDSLASH)` Excel read a date but set locale to Africaans
[Screenshot Excel date 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edCoS.png)

How can i set a German date (dd.mm.yyyy) correct with phpspreadsheet?

Thank you 
 Othmar

Answer (score 4):

Use a string value instead of the built-in constants:

```
->setFormatCode('DD.MM.YYYY')
```